# Adding Full Text to SQL Server 2014 - do I have to be careful about versions of installation media?

Tags: sql-server, installation, full-text-search

Hi I'm developer not a DBA, so I'm fairly clueless. I need to add Full Text Indexing to a SQL Server 2014 server. It's a production server on a HyperV VM.

- Do I need to be careful about specific versions of the installation media. When I upgraded my dev machine I simply mounted the installation media as a DVD. I just used the most recent 2016 SQL Dev ISO.
- It's a licenced sever and I have MSDN subscription so I have access to media. Will generic ISOs be OK?
- I'm a little unsure of the environment, I'm unsure how easy it will be to mount the ISO. Is there a way to install from binaries. When playing around installing on my dev machine, I saw a few blog posts saying you could get issues unless the ISO is mounted.